# My Vue.js code is giving me null, instead of adm's ID with idRecord comparison

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am just receiving the null as return after trying to solve by using the forEach() and I don't knw what to do from now on.

`/*
console.log(this.optionIdRecord)

```
console.log(this.Business)
for (let i = 0; i < this.optionIdRecord.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.Business.length; j++) {
    if (this.Business[j].idRecord == this.optionIdRecord[i].id) {
      console.log(this.Business[j])
      console.log(this.optionIdRecord[i])
    }
  }
}
*/
this.optionIdRecord.forEach((admElement) => {
  this.Business.forEach((businessElement) => {
    if (admElement.id === businessElement.idRecord) {
      console.log(admElement)
      console.log(businessElement)
    }
  })
})`
```

Comment: Would you please share the whole script block and update the question? It is not possible to understand which value is null from the code above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.